# How to use JobControl in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to merge two files into one.
I made two mappers to read, and one reducer to join.

```
        JobConf classifiedConf = new JobConf(new Configuration());
            classifiedConf.setJarByClass(myjob.class);
    classifiedConf.setJobName("classifiedjob");
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(classifiedConf,classifiedInputPath );
    classifiedConf.setMapperClass(ClassifiedMapper.class);
    classifiedConf.setMapOutputKeyClass(TextPair.class);
    classifiedConf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    Job classifiedJob = new Job(classifiedConf);
    //first mapper config

    JobConf featureConf = new JobConf(new Configuration());
    featureConf.setJobName("featureJob");
            featureConf.setJarByClass(myjob.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(featureConf, featuresInputPath);
    featureConf.setMapperClass(FeatureMapper.class);
    featureConf.setMapOutputKeyClass(TextPair.class);
    featureConf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    Job featureJob = new Job(featureConf);
            //second mapper config

    JobConf joinConf = new JobConf(new Configuration());
    joinConf.setJobName("joinJob");
            joinConf.setJarByClass(myjob.class);
    joinConf.setReducerClass(JoinReducer.class);
    joinConf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    joinConf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    Job joinJob = new Job(joinConf);
             //reducer config
             //JobControl config
            joinJob.addDependingJob(featureJob);
    joinJob.addDependingJob(classifiedJob);
    secondJob.addDependingJob(joinJob);
    JobControl jobControl = new JobControl("jobControl");
    jobControl.addJob(classifiedJob);
    jobControl.addJob(featureJob);
    jobControl.addJob(secondJob);

    Thread thread = new Thread(jobControl);
    thread.start();
    while(jobControl.allFinished()){
        jobControl.stop();
    }
```

But, I get this message:
WARN mapred.JobClient:

```
Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
```

anyone help please..................

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Hadoop are you using?

The warning you get will stop the program?

You don't need to use setJarByClass(). You can see my snippet, I can run it without using setJarByClass() method.

```
JobConf job = new JobConf(PageRankJob.class);
job.setJobName("PageRankJob");

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

job.setMapperClass(PageRankMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(PageRankReducer.class);

job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

JobClient.runJob(job);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your Job this way:

```
public class MyApp extends Configured implements Tool {

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
      // Configuration processed by ToolRunner
      Configuration conf = getConf();

      // Create a JobConf using the processed conf
      JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, MyApp.class);

      // Process custom command-line options
      Path in = new Path(args[1]);
      Path out = new Path(args[2]);

      // Specify various job-specific parameters     
      job.setJobName("my-app");
      job.setInputPath(in);
      job.setOutputPath(out);
      job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
      job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

      // Submit the job, then poll for progress until the job is complete
      JobClient.runJob(job);
      return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      // Let ToolRunner handle generic command-line options 
      int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MyApp(), args);

      System.exit(res);
    }
}
```

This comes straight out of Hadoop's documentation [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html).

So basically your job needs to inherit from `Configured` and implement `Tool`. This will force you to implement `run()`. Then start your job from your main class using `Toolrunner.run(<your job>, <args>)` and the warning will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this code in the driver `job.setJarByClass(MapperClassName.class);`